# I want angular to accesss a URL and fetch STL file which can be reused for further processing

Tags: angular, url, 3d

The path or the URL to the STL file  is obtained as an input from the user or should come from the backend. Any idea how should I approach the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please post an example maybe of your code or something? So that we can better understand what you want to do.

But have a look at HttpClient https://angular.io/guide/http

If you just want to fetch data from a server, you will have to inject the HttpClient in your constructor like:

```
export class yourClass {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

Then you can do a function to fetch the data like:

```
fetchData(): void {
   this.http.get('http://www.exampleToFetch.com')
   .subscribe((response: string) => {
       // response is now the fetched data
       this.stlData = response; //asign the fetched data to a variable
    })
}
```

Important is that you have to subscribe to the http-request as the HttpClient.get() Method returns an observable!